# Encrypting existing tar.gz archive

Tags: tar, openssl, gzip

I know of a method to encrypt a tar.gz archive while creating it (*not sure if it's a recommend one*):

```
tar -czvf /path/to/save/archive.tar.gz -C /path/to/archive . | 
openssl des3 -salt -k #PASSWORD# | dd of=archive
```

The problem is that I have some large existing archives that I'd like to encrypt also, but I'm not sure if that is possible without re-archiving everything?

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt any existing file with the same encryption tool and options, using standard shell redirection.  For example:

```
openssl des3 -salt -k #PASSWORD# < oldfile.tar.gz > newfile.tar.gz
```

if you want to replace the old file with the new encrypted version, then:

```
openssl des3 -salt -k #PASSWORD# < oldfile.tar.gz > newfile.tar.gz && mv -f newfile.tar.gz oldfile.tar.gz
```

Comment: I might be trying to decrypt incorrectly, but when i use `openssl des3 -d -k #PASSWORD# | tar -C tmp -xvf newfile.tar.gz` there's an error: `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error reading input file`

Comment: newfile.tar.gz needs to be read by openssl, not an arg to tar.  `openssl des3 -d -k #PASSWORD# < newfile.tar.gz | tar xvfz - -C tmp`

Comment: if you are seeing a warning, check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093591/how-should-i-change-encryption-according-to-warning-deprecated-key-derivat